# Как взять данные обьекта полученные динамически и отобразить их как текст?

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Работаю на данный момент с google-analytics при запросе он динамический отправляет мне ответ.Если не ошибаюсь это **JSON** файл

Вот [здесь](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js?hl=ru) можете посмотреть на код с которым я работаю я проста скачал весь html и изменил там только ID клиента и добавил  `"dimensions":"ga:country"` после этого кода `"metrics":"ga:users",` и вот при обновлении страницы он выдает мне обьект при котором выводится *сколько людей зашли на сайт и из какого региона* .

Но тут загвоздка в том что он дает мне код а мне надо взять с этого кода определенные обьекты и их свойства и показать их на странице как нормальный текст.

Вот код который google-analytics api мне возвращает

```
{
  "kind": "analytics#gaData",
  "id": "тут мой ID",
  "query": {
    "start-date": "30daysAgo", //30 дневная статистика
    "end-date": "today", //последная дата сегодня
    "ids": "ga:172427234",
    "dimensions": "ga:country", //регионы
    "metrics": [
      "ga:users" //user-ы
    ],
    "start-index": 1,
    "max-results": 1000
  },
  "itemsPerPage": 1000,
  "totalResults": 7,
  "selfLink": "тут ссылка какая то",
  "profileInfo": {
    "profileId": "172427234",
    "accountId": "116539423",
    "webPropertyId": "UA-116539423-1",
    "internalWebPropertyId": "172991088",
    "profileName": "Все данные по веб-сайту",
    "tableId": "ga:172427234"
  },
  "containsSampledData": false,
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "ga:country",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:users",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:users": "43523" //все user-ы которые зашли на сайт
  },
  "rows": [ // регионы из которых зашли на сайт и сколько  user-а зашел с каждого региона 
    [
      "Dubai",
      "28961"
    ],
    [
      "Germany",
      "1400"
    ],
    [
      "Netherlands",
      "111"
    ],
    [
      "Poland",
      "10"
    ],
    [
      "Russia",
      "1021"
    ],
    [
      "Ukraine",
      "28"
    ],
    [
      "United States",
      "11992"
    ]
  ]
}
```

С этого кода мне надо извлечь из обьекта `"totalsForAllResults":` значение свойства `"ga:users":` то есть число который он выдает **43523** или любое другое число

Также имя каждой страны и число пользователей (одним словом все свойства находящийся в массиве **row** )

Очень прошу помогите.

Comment: JSON.parse() https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если представить, что response - результат запроса.

const r = JSON.parse(response);
const needed = r.totalsForAllResults['ga:users'];

Comment: шас проверью и приму ответ если сработает